# Nginx configuration for docker repos in Artifactory

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy, artifactory

I have the following conf for nginx to set up docker repos in artifactory

```
upstream artifactory_lb {
        server backup_artifactory_server:8081 backup;
        server main_artifactory_server:8081;

}

log_format upstreamlog '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user - $server_name  to: $upstream_addr: $request upstream_response_time $upstream_response_time msec $msec request_time $request_time';

ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/myCert.pem
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/myKey
ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443  ssl;
        client_max_body_size 2048M;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreamlog;
        location /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow all;
                }
}

# Server configuration

server {
    listen 2222 ssl;
    server_name this_proxy.com;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
        set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
    }

    rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/inhouse_images/$1/$2;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {
    allow all;
    proxy_read_timeout  900;
    proxy_pass_header   Server;
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
    proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     # proxy_pass http://artifactory_lb;
    proxy_pass http://backup_artifactory_server:8081/artifactory/;

    }
  }
```

This works fine, although, by setting the 'proxy_pass' directive to point to the loadbalancer instance introduces a single point failure. Why does it need to be routed to '/artifactory'?

What will be the best way to fix this? Creating a new group of upstream servers seems redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the following

```
 rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /api/docker/inhouse_images/$1/$2;
```

To the following

```
 rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/inhouse_images/$1/$2;
```

And pointing the proxy_pass directive to the upstream servers